# C# Setting each character in a string to an asterisk (*) if a user has selected "Hidden" function

Tags: c#, string, char

learning C# at the moment. Just wondering if it's possible to set all the characters in a string to an asterisk symbol if a user has selected to hide the visibility of a password. Here is what I have so far:

```
private string Password
{ get; set; }

public bool Hidden
{ get; private set; }

public PasswordManager(string password, bool hidden)
{
  Password = password;
  Hidden = hidden;
}
public void Display()
{
  if (Hidden == false)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(password);
  }
  else if (Hidden == true)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("*");
  }
}
```

As you can see, if the Hidden bool is true, the Console.WriteLine needs to write the asterisk but I'd like it to write an asterisk for each character. Would it be possible to do something like a foreach loop not for string contents but rather for the characters in a given string. Using something like string.Length? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Don't do this!  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Never store a user password.  Store a hash of the password using a long running algorithm (at least 1 second).  Use byte array, not string, then you can zero the memory after you've hashed the password.

Comment: By the way, that `else` is enough, you don't need that `if` after it

Comment: It's better to display a fixed number of *'s so you don't give a hint to the password length. And when you hash the password, you don't know its length anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the for loop to print each character as *:

```
public void Display()   
{
   if (Hidden == false)
   {
        Console.WriteLine(password);
   }
   else if (Hidden == true)
   {
       //Console.WriteLine("*");
       for(int i=0; i<password.Length;i++)
            Console.Write('*');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the `string` class has [a constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-string-ctor(system-char-system-int32)) that *"initializes a new instance of the String class to the value indicated by a specified Unicode character repeated a specified number of times"*, you could just replace:

```
Console.WriteLine("*");
```

with:

```
Console.WriteLine(new string('*', password.Length));
```

In fact, the whole method could be simplified to:

```
public void Display()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Hidden ? new string('*', password.Length) : password);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a for loop to print a star for each character in the password. The number of times you want to iterate is the length of the password string.